# How do I increase PHP of my wordpress blog

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I increase my PHP ?

PHP Max Input Vars:
WP Memory Limit:

This kind of thing.
Thanks everyone!!!

Comment: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/increase-memory-limit/ This looks promising. Next time, have a more specific question. We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." You also must provide your question **as text**, not as images.

Comment: Just download more PHP if you need it. It's the same process as downloading more RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue most often in the case of Wordpress admin pages not passing all of the request variables from a page submission. If that is the case for you, do the following:

-In your `wp_admin` directory, create a file called `php.ini`

-In that file, you can place the following line:

```
max_input_vars = 1500
```

Adjust the number to meet your needs.

If it is your frontend returning this issue, Create the same file in your root directory. If it is ajax or any backend page, place it in `/wp_admin`.

Php.ini files need to exist in the same directory that the original script file executed from to affect the server for that execution. All frontend pages originate from the root directory (index.php). All admin pages and ajax requests originate from the wp_admin directory.